# css not working when trying to center self

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to make an item center,but somehow it not work

Here is html part:

```
    <div>
   
      <div className={styles.unanswerQuestionContainer}>
        <div className={styles.headerContainer}>
          <div>Unanswered Questions</div>
          <div>Answered Questions</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is css part:

```
.unanswerQuestionContainer {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 60vw;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  align-self: center;
}
.headerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But it show something like this:

[image]

It do not center the div, how can i center this ??
Edit: When i try to inspect then it show all of this is margin:
[image]

Comment: which element are you exactly trying to center?

Comment: It is `unanswerQuestionContainer`

Comment: why did you set this ```margin: 20px 0 0 0;``` if you want it centered?

Comment: As you can see the yellow mark as margin

Answer (score 2):

You need to add following style to outer div(parent) `unanswerQuestionContainer`

```
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
```

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
.unanswerQuestionContainer {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 60vw;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  align-self: center;
}
.headerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.outer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   
      <div class="unanswerQuestionContainer">
        <div class="headerContainer">
          <div>Unanswered Questions</div>
          <div>Answered Questions</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to adjust which css properties you will use in order to prevent the two h1 from overlapping.

```
  <div className={styles.unanswerQuestionContainer}>
    <div class="Questions">
      <p id="question-type">Answered Question</p>
      <p id="question-type">Unanswered Question</p>
    </div>
  </div>


.questions h1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```